# Why does the didSelectRowAt function highlight multiple rows?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to be able to highlight my custom cell text labels when the cells are selected
Currently I am able to highlight them but when I scroll down the table few other cells labels that I haven't selected are also highlighted.

I know it probably has to do with the dequeue reusable cells but I have't been able to fix it.

I have tried using the didSelectRowAt function approach and I have also tried allowing multiple selection for my tableview and using the setSelected function in my customCell class

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! RecommendationCell


            if cell.isSelected {
                if cell.label.textColor == UIColor.highlightColor {
                    cell.label.textColor = .white
                } else  {
                    cell.label.textColor = UIColor.highlightColor
                }
            }
}


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        if selected {
            self.label.textColor = UIColor.highlightColor
        }

    }
```

Comment: write code for both if and else case if it is not selected what should be label colour then it will work as we have reuse cells. so the cell can take the previous state so check that I guess issue will be there.

Comment: If you call setSelected(true) followed by setSelected(false), the label.textColor is changed but not changed back.

Comment: Show code in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the `UITableView` will reuse the cells.

You have to update the cell (in your case the background color) state in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    self.label.textColor = cell.isSelected ? UIColor.highlightColor : UIColor.label
}
```

A slightly more elegant solution would be to override the `prepareForReuse` in your custom cell class (pick either one).

```
class RecommendationCell : UITableViewCell
{
    override func prepareForReuse()
    {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        self.label.color = self.isSelected ? UIColor.highlight : UIColor.label
    }
}
```

You can read more about [prepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse) in the official documentation.